# Custom Post Type and Breadcrumbs Conflict

Tags: custom-post-types, errors, breadcrumb

[image: An example of the extra space]

I have a custom post type. It seems the breadcrumbs have an extra space for a parent page (which does not exist) inserted. You can see this in the image I attached.

What is happening with theis custom post type that is causing this extra, non-existent parent?

Here is my custom page type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_result' );

function register_cpt_result() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Case Results', 'result' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Result', 'result' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'result' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Result', 'result' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Result', 'result' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Result', 'result' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Result', 'result' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Case Results', 'result' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No case results found', 'result' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No case results found in Trash', 'result' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Result:', 'result' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Case Results', 'result' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'My firm\'s case results',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,


        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'result', $args );
}
```

Here is my breadcrumbs function:

```
function crumbs() {
    if ((is_page() && ! is_category()) || is_archive() || is_single() || is_single()) {
        $crumbs = '';
        $crumbs .= '<div class="crumbs"><span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">';
        $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">Home</a></span>';
        $post_ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);

        if ($post_ancestors) {
            $post_ancestors = array_reverse($post_ancestors);
            foreach ($post_ancestors as $crumb)
                $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_permalink($crumb).'">'.get_the_title($crumb).'</a></span>';
        }
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            $category = get_the_category();
            $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a></span>';
        }
        if (!is_category())
            $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><span class="crumbs-last" property="v:title">'.get_the_title().'</span></span>';
        $crumbs .= '</span></div>';
        $close_crumb = '</span>';
        $open_crumb = '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">';
        $separator = '<span class="separator">→</span>';
        echo str_replace($close_crumb.$open_crumb, $close_crumb.$separator.$open_crumb, $crumbs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to add condition: if(get_post_type() == 'result'){...manual add your cpt title...or use get_post_type_object('result')->labels->name...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom post type matches the conditional `is_single()`, so this part is trying to output the category the post is assigned to, which I'm assuming doesn't exist:

```
if (is_category() || is_single()) {
    $category = get_the_category();
    $crumbs .= '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a></span>';
}
```

either check if `$category` contains a category, or change `is_single` to just check the `post` post type:

```
if (is_category() || is_singular('post')) {
```